# Custom List View image click in android

Tags: android

I create one Custom List View. I want to zoom image when I click Imageview. Its similar to whats app. when I click DP of any person that time it zoom. Similar I want in my project. How can it work.

[image]

[image: I want just like this]
Thanks in advance friends.!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use the "Zooming a View" example from Android Dev site

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

It is quite simple and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

There is many of the ways to do that.

I can explain here with `PopupWindow`

Step 1:

```
your_main_imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final View anchorView) {
View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                                    R.layout.popup_layout, null);
//Note: Add an imageView in this popup_layout.
ImageView image_button = (ImageView) popupView
                                    .findViewById(R.id.your_imageview);
//Set image for imageView here
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
// If the PopupWindow should be focusable
                            popupWindow.setFocusable(false);
                            popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
                            // If you need the PopupWindow to dismiss when when
                            // touched outside
                            popupWindow
                                    .setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());

                            final int location[] = new int[2];

                            // Get the View's(the one that was clicked in the
                            // Fragment) location
                            anchorView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
anchorView.post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // Using location, the PopupWindow will be
                                    // displayed right under anchorView
                                    popupWindow.showAtLocation(
                                            anchorView,
                                            Gravity.NO_GRAVITY,
                                            location[0],
                                            location[1]
                                                    + anchorView.getHeight());
                                }
                            });


}
```

This is not complete code. Ask any doubts i will explain in comments

Comment: Its working partially. When I click on Image that time Image is hiding and other part is showing in pop up window.

Comment: Then you need to make changes in popup_layout. That is in my code for inflate